# Dynamic id for primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

When generating multiple datatables I need to set dynamic id for each table in order to export the data.

Here is the following code I expected to work:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{beans}" var="bean">
 <h:commandLink>
   <h:outputText value="Export"/>
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{bean.id}" fileName="exp" pageOnly="true"/>         
 </h:commandLink>
 <p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var={item}>
   <c:set target="#{component}" property="id" value="#{bean.id}"/>
  .
  .
 </p:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Instead, It says component not found. Checking the html of the datatable shows that id is not set.

Setting the id immediatelly to the table results in error of 'Empty id not allowed'.

Anyone have solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you need a dynamic id for this?

Comment: I assume this based on dataexporter where I have to provide known id of the table. I actually dint't thought about just find the id of the table.

Comment: Kukeltje you are right.

Comment: But.... @JasperdeVries also has a point... maybe you do not need dynamic id's https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/selector.xhtml or https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/search.xhtml might help too, using it in the 'target'

Comment: Did you try with a fixed id?

Comment: <c:forEach works just fine. Thank you